# Is it detrimental to performance to reference all of an entity type in mapStateToProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, normalization, normalizr

I've been building quite an extensive app with React, Redux and Normalizr but have been struggling with a totally excessive number of redundant render cycles, and am now thinking I've perhaps misunderstood how to combine `mapStateToProps` and Normalizr.

In my `mapStateToProps`, I'm referencing all of a certain entity type, which I can then use to get an entity from its ID:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        allMilestones: state.account.entities.milestones,
        allTasks: state.account.entities.tasks,
    }
}
```

Using the above `mapStateToProps`, whenever I need to get an entity, I can just go (for example) `const taskObject = this.props.allTasks[taskId]`. Quick and convenient, but I understand this means there's a lot of props being passed around - I thought passing around references wouldn't be a big deal, but then I noticed everything was re-rendering just, all the time.

Would this be a likely culprit for an unreasonable amount of render cycles?

If so, could I expect implementing Reselect for all of these cases would positively affect performance?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but this is a guesstimation without benchmarks (and you should try to clarify that yourself before making any optimisations). React-Redux will do a comparison of all of the keys of the object returned from `mapStateToProps` and will rerender if any are different.

If the reference changes each time - because you're using an immutable Map, for example - then the component will re-render any time `mapStateToProps()` is called.

You should try to make the return value more stable by only returning what is required by the connected component.

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#return-values-determine-if-your-component-re-renders